# How to properly do data binding in Xamarin Forms?

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I'm incredibly new to Xamarin Forms and I'm super lost. Could someone please give me an example of primary data binding to a label using MVVM?

I currently have View of `InformationPage` ViewModel of `InformationPageModel` and Model of `ResourceGatheringLogic`.

I was trying to figure out how to read JSON from embedded resources but I can't even properly bind a string to display `HelloWorld` for data binding.

I would only like a very simple example of how to properly do this and I can most likely do the rest. Many Thanks in advance.

My `.xaml`

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:uCue_Game.ViewModel"
             xmlns:xct="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2020/toolkit"
             x:Class="uCue_Game.View.InformationPage">
    <ContentPage.BindingContext>
        <local:InformationPageModel/>
    </ContentPage.BindingContext>

    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="1*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <Frame BackgroundColor="LightGreen"
               VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"
               HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand">
            <Label Text="{Binding MediaSource}"
                   TextColor="Black"
                   FontSize="20"
                   FontAttributes="Bold"
                   VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
                   HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
                   HeightRequest="300"
                   WidthRequest="300"/>
        </Frame>
    </Grid>
    
</ContentPage>
```

My `.xaml.cs`

```
namespace uCue_Game.View
{
    using Xamarin.Forms;


    public partial class InformationPage : ContentPage
    {
        public InformationPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
    }
}
```

My ViewModel `.cs` Ignore the SetMediaSource it is for later use.

```
namespace uCue_Game.ViewModel
{
    using global::Model;
    using Xamarin.Forms;

    public class InformationPageModel
    {
        IMediaSource mediaSource;
        public string MediaSource = "Hello";

        public InformationPageModel()
        {
            this.mediaSource = DependencyService.Get<IMediaSource>();
            //SetMediaSource();
        }

        public void SetMediaSource()
        {
            if (mediaSource != null)
                return;

            MediaSource = mediaSource.GetMediaSource();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: you can only bind to **public properties**.  `MediaSource` is not a C# property

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can only bind to **public properties**

```
public string MediaSource { get; set; } = "Hello";
```